# How to get records from col "WON" in Odoo CRM

Tags: python-3.6, odoo, crm

The problem:
In Odoo 11 CRM, when the record moves to column "WON" - the info about this record should be translated to Telegram Channel.

The first I did is started the Odoo 11 on VM on Google Cloud Platform to test it.

But now I can`t understand how to get information from column "WON".

I found that OdooRPC can do something like that, but now I can get only information about logined user, company and database and not from CRM module.

```
#python3.6

import odoorpc

# Prepare the connection to the server
odoo = odoorpc.ODOO('**.***.**.**', port=8069)
# Check available databases
print(odoo.db.list())
# Login
odoo.login('DB', 'login', 'password')
# Current user
user = odoo.env.user
print(user.name) # name of the user connected
print(user.company_id.name) # the name of its company
# Simple 'raw' query
user_data = odoo.execute('res.users', 'read', [user.id])
print(user_data)
```

Help me with understanding the way how to get info from CRM module

Comment: What is the problem with your existing code?

Comment: There is no problem with thos code. It's just to show what info I can get with odoorpc, but its not that I need.

Answer (score 0):

To get "won" opportunities, you need to apply a filter to all `crm.lead` records. There are two approaches.

1. By default, once an opportunity is marked as "won", its `probability` becomes 100.

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'crm.lead', 'search',
    [[['probability', '=', 100]]])
```

2. In case you have changed the default, can first seach `crm.stage` for the name "won" and get the ID, then search `crm.lead` to find records that has `stage_id` equal to the ID of "won".

```
# To get stage ID of "Won"
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'crm.stage', 'search',
    [[['name', '=', 'won']]])

# Find "Won" records
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'crm.lead', 'search',
    [[['stage_id', '=', id_of_your_won_stage]]])
```

Comment: That`s I need - 'crm.stage'. Thanks